# Display Working Days from two dates in recordset results PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, formula

I have a record set that is pulling various pieces of information from a SQL database including dates. What I'd like to do is work out the number of working days from a specific date to todays date. I'm basically working out how many working days have passed since the first date.

I don't have an issue working out the working days, there are many very helpful posts on here. The issue I have is that I need this to recur on each line in the table that is filled from the database. But as the variables are different for each row, the page is blank after the first result, because I assume the script is trying to run again using the same named variables.

Is there a way to enclose the php code for this sum so that it can run in the next row with the same variables without the previous row interfering?

Thanks in advance for help.

```html
<?php
//The function returns the no. of business days between two dates and it skips the holidays
function getWorkingDays($startDate,$endDate){
    // do strtotime calculations just once
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);


    //The total number of days between the two dates. We compute the no. of seconds and divide it to 60*60*24
    //We add one to inlude both dates in the interval.
    $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;

    $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
    $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

    //It will return 1 if it's Monday,.. ,7 for Sunday
    $the_first_day_of_week = date("N", $startDate);
    $the_last_day_of_week = date("N", $endDate);

    //---->The two can be equal in leap years when february has 29 days, the equal sign is added here
    //In the first case the whole interval is within a week, in the second case the interval falls in two weeks.
    if ($the_first_day_of_week <= $the_last_day_of_week) {
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 6 && 6 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 7 && 7 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
    }
    else {
        // (edit by Tokes to fix an edge case where the start day was a Sunday
        // and the end day was NOT a Saturday)

        // the day of the week for start is later than the day of the week for end
        if ($the_first_day_of_week == 7) {
            // if the start date is a Sunday, then we definitely subtract 1 day
            $no_remaining_days--;

            if ($the_last_day_of_week == 6) {
                // if the end date is a Saturday, then we subtract another day
                $no_remaining_days--;
            }
        }
        else {
            // the start date was a Saturday (or earlier), and the end date was (Mon..Fri)
            // so we skip an entire weekend and subtract 2 days
            $no_remaining_days -= 2;
        }
    }

    //The no. of business days is: (number of weeks between the two dates) * (5 working days) + the remainder
//---->february in none leap years gave a remainder of 0 but still calculated weekends between first and last day, this is one way to fix it
   $workingDays = $no_full_weeks * 5;
    if ($no_remaining_days > 0 )
    {
      $workingDays += $no_remaining_days;
    }

    //We subtract the holidays
    foreach($holidays as $holiday){
        $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday);
        //If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
        if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N",$time_stamp) != 6 && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7)
            $workingDays--;
    }

    return $workingDays;
}
$approval = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row_rsworksorders1['intraartapproval']));
$w_days = getWorkingDays($approval,(date('Y-m-d'))) . ' Days';

echo $w_days;
?>
```

The date being pulled from the database is $row_rsworksorders1['intraartapproval'])

Comment: what you have tried so far ,please update your code

Comment: I've updated with the code.

Comment: what will be your input and what you want as output?

Comment: So the date for $row_rsworksorders1['intraartapproval']) is stored as '2015-06-03'.

So I need to display the amount working days that have passed since this date to todays date so it says for instance: '4 Days'.

Comment: ok it give ouput as 1 day , what you would expect

Comment: As I said above, it works fine for the first row in the record set. But I am using DO and WHILE to repeat until all rows are shown and the page stops loading as soon as it gets to this code on the second row.

Comment: what will be the result you get on the second row of your record set

Comment: There is no result. The code doesn't run.

Comment: what will be the the second row of your record set

Comment: I'm sorry but you don't seem to understand what I am asking. Can anyone else help? Thank you.